# error : 'CONTAINS' is not recognized as a function or procedure

Tags: sql, derby

I'm trying to run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CHANNELS 
WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'm' )
```

but I get this error:

> 'CONTAINS' is not recognized as a function or procedure.

As I know this is the right syntax or am I wrong?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: @scaisEdge SQuirrel  Sql

Comment: Squirrel is a SQL client application that can connect to many different DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check whether `name` field contains `m` or not, use `LIKE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM CHANNELS WHERE name LIKE '%m%'
```